# Set ENV variables in tomcat7 maven plugin

Tags: java, environment-variables, tomcat7-maven-plugin

Is there a way to set ENV variables through `tomcat7-maven-plugin` such that they appear in `System.getenv()`?

The system properties can be set using the `<systemProperties>` that appear in `System.getProperties()` map. I am looking for a similar way to pass environment variables.

Comment: Where you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to set ENV variables through tomcat7-maven-plugin such that they appear in System.getenv()?

Yes and no. You can pass ENV variables but they wont appear by System.getenv(). Example:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <foo>${env.FOO}</foo>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score -1):

This has been answered here: [Setting User Environment Variables for tomcat on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456863/setting-user-environment-variables-for-tomcat-on-windows)

> From an admin command prompt do the following command:
>
> ```
> tomcat8 //US//YourServiceName ++Environment varname=value
> ```
>
> You can set more than one variable by separating them with a semicolon
>   (;) or a hash (#).

Comment: This will not help setting environment variables when running the Tomcat Maven plugin as part of a build